# Is there a better way to use sam var multiple a string modulo formatting?

Tags: python

I have a row counter in my python code and want to build a Excel formula based on this counter. At the moment I use this code, but I think it is not really python like. Is there a better way to express that?

```
ws["K%d" % counter] = "=F%i*25+G%i*50+H%i*75+I%i*100" % (counter, counter, counter, counter)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the versions below:

```
# Still using the % operator:
ws["K%d" % counter] = "=F%(c)i*25+G%(c)i*50+H%(c)i*75+I%(c)i*100" % dict(c=counter)
# Using .format()
ws["K%d" % counter] = "=F{c}*25+G{c}*50+H{c}*75+I{c}*100".format(c=counter)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well there are plenty of methods to achieve desired output:

1. With positional argument of [string.format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.format#str.format)

   ```
   ws["K%d" % counter] = "=F{0}*25+G{0}*50+H{0}*75+I%{0}*100".format(counter)
   ```
2. With keyword argument of [string.format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.format#str.format)

   ```
   ws["K%d" % counter] = "=F{c}*25+G{c}*50+H{c}*75+I{c}*100".format(c=counter)
   ```
3. With [string.Template](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html?highlight=template#string.Template)

   ```
   import string
   ws["K%d" % counter] = string.Template("=F$c*25+G$c*50+H$c*75+I%$c*100").substitute(c=counter)
   ```

**Good Luck!**